# Exporting values passed to enquos as string of format name1,name2, nameN,

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

In this example, I have a simple function taking variable names passed via `...` and making use of the [`enquos`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tidyeval.html) function in order to pass them to [`group_by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html) operator in dplyr.

## Basic function

```
#  Libraries
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
sample_function <- function(x, ...) {
    group_vars <- enquos(...)

    x %>%
        group_by(!!!group_vars) %>%
        summarise(num_obs = n())
}
```

### Results

```
mtcars %>% sample_function(cyl, am)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl    am num_obs
  <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1     4     0       3
2     4     1       8
3     6     0       4
4     6     1       3
5     8     0      12
6     8     1       2
```

## Problem

I would like to expand the function above and in addition to the produced results create a new scalar character that would reflect names of variables passed to `enquos` in a format: `"var1, var2, ..."`.

### Attempt

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
sample_function <- function(x, ...) {
    group_vars <- enquos(...)

    # Problem:
    # Create test object of quoted variables
    assign(x = "used_group_variables",
           value = quo_text(group_vars),
           envir = globalenv())

    # Summary
    x %>%
        group_by(!!!group_vars) %>%
        summarise(num_obs = n())
}
```

#### Results

*Produced string does not match the desired format.*

```
used_group_variables
# [1] "structure(list(~cyl, ~am), .Names = c(\"\", \"\"), class = c(\"quosures\", \n\"list\"))"
```

#### Desired results

*Only names of all variables initially passed via `enquos` are returned and pasted together with "`" as a separator.*

```
used_group_variables
# "cyl, am"
```

---

## Notes

- Admittedly, assigning values to the global environment from the inside of a function is not a good practice. This is only done for illustrative purposes. In effect, the key goal is to coerce whatever sits within `enquos` to string of format `"name1, name2, ..."`.

Comment: `value = toString(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$\`...\`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sapply` for that and collapse with `toString`:

```
sample_function <- function(x, ...) {
  group_vars <- enquos(...)

  assign(x = "used_group_variables",
         value = toString(sapply(group_vars, quo_name)),
         envir = globalenv())

  x %>%
    group_by(!!!group_vars) %>%
    summarise(num_obs = n())
}
```

Output:

```
mtcars %>% sample_function(am, cyl)

used_group_variables
# [1] "am, cyl"
```

---

**Edit**: As suggested by @LionelHenry in the comment, you may want to use `as_label` instead of `quo_name` as the latter is misleading and will likely be deprecated.

Comment: That's a good idea. Or even `map_chr(enquo_stuff, quo_name)`  and then paste, if I want to stay more within the *tidyverse*.

Comment: I recommend `as_label()` or `as_string()` (depending on what you're trying to achieve) instead of `quo_name()`, which is likely to be deprecated (since it has such a misleading name).